# Write to TestResults on TFS Build Server from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, tfs

On the TFS 2013 BuildServer, i run Post-Test PowerShellScript to Execute JavaScript Unit Test using Grunt. This produces the .xml file on the build server.

I want to write the results from .xml to the TestResult of TFS Server.

Is there a way to do this ?

Looking for a way to push the Pass and Faile results of JavaScript Test into TestResult(.trx) of TFS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vstest.console.exe to publish test results.  See this blog post on publishing test results using vstest: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/12/06/publishing-test-results-through-command-line-test-runner.aspx  You should be able to invoke that exe from an InvokeProcess activity.

Answer (score 1):

vstest.console.exe with TfsPublisher switch would allow you to run tests results from a unit test run executed by vstest.console.exe. Since, you are using JavaScript unit test with Grunt, that won't work.

Your best bet is to create an activity that reads information from the xml file and publish results to you team build. Have a look at this project

https://github.com/hamidshahid/TfsBuildResultPublisher

There are bits of code that you an use from this project specially around adding your own test results information.